# What does "one" refer to in: “one that is subsequently rejected…”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, antecedents

Here is a sentence from an LSAT:

> It draws an analogy between semiplaning monohulls and conventional
> ships that constitutes an objection to the argument's main conclusion,
> one that is subsequently rejected by appeal to another analogy.
> [source](https://gmatclub.com/forum/engineer-semiplaning-monohulls-are-a-new-kind-of-ship-272718.html)

Does "one" refer to the "main conclusion" or "an objection"? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one) defines **one** as a pronoun meaning

> used to refer to a particular thing or person within a group or range of things or people that are possible or available

As an example, you might say:

> I have picked some apples. Would you like **one**?

In this sentence, **one** refers to one of the group of apples.

"**an** objection" is one of a group of objections, so **one** could refer to it, but "**the** ... main conclusion" is the only main conclusion, so **one** cannot refer to it.